# JQuery / CSS3 animation conflicts

Tags: jquery, css

I have a little css3 animation that makes my text go from white to blue and then blue to white (comes back to normal when mouse is not on the element anymore).

```
nav a {
display: block;
height: 20px;
font-size: 16px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFFFFF;
transition: color 1s;
-webkit-transition: color 1s;
}

nav a:hover {
color: #0092DB;
}
```

This works fine, until this animation by jquery is launched:

```
$(function() {
$('#headerCenter img').hover(
    function () {
        $('nav a').animate({
            color: "#0092DB"
        }, 500);
    },
    function () {
        $('nav a').animate({
            color: "#FFFFFF"
        }, 500);
    })
})
```

The CSS3 are for individual < li > animations and the jquery is an animation for all the < li > when we hover over the logo.

I noticed that when the Jquery animation is launched, it puts a style attribute to my < a >, with the right color and kind of erases the the color in the stylesheet.

[image]

[image]

I think this is why my CSS3 animation does not work anymore, because it needs the color: #FFFFFF to make the transition. Hopefuly, you have a solution!!

Comment: It seems you are launching two different animations on the same element(s). I would recommend using a more narrow selector for your jQuery animation so that it does not match the CSS for your other animation.

Comment: From what I understand, your jQuery animation changes the CSS of the elements that should actually not be part of that animation but rather have a CSS animation. Changing the jQuery selector to only match the objects that you want animated should prevent jQuery fromm changing unrelated objects' CSS properties.

Comment: No, the nav a are part of the jquery animation. In the Css3 animation, they go from white to blue individually and in the JQuery animation, they go from white to blue in a group

Comment: Could you setup jsfiddle? Do you use JQuery Ui for color animation?

Comment: Ok I will do a jsfiddle, but it's the same code..
And I use JQuery Color for the color animation.

Comment: Ahh can't do the jsfiddle, I'm using wordpress :\

Comment: I found the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
$('#headerCenter img').hover(
    function () {
        $('nav a').animate({
            color: "#0092DB"
        }, 500);
    },
    function () {
        $('nav a').animate({
            color: "#FFFFFF"
        }, 500, function () {
            $('nav a').removeAttr('style');
        });
    })
})
```

Simply added a callback function to delete de inline styling!

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you do this:

Add an extra css class to the equation:

```
nav a:hover, nav.active {
color: #0092DB;
}
```

then do this

```
$(function() {
$('#headerCenter img').hover(
    function () {
        $('nav').addClass('active')
    },
    function () {
        $('nav').removeClass('active')
    })
})
```